# i want implement animation for Floating Button

Tags: android, android-animation, floating-action-button

I want to give a full rotation animation to my floating button, i have the code, but  its only  animating like rotating half. i want rotate the floating button from a position and it should end with the same position where it started( a full rotation ) , how to do that ?

here is my code , i want some one to modify the value or code

```
  final OvershootInterpolator interpolator = new OvershootInterpolator();
            ViewCompat.animate(fab).
                    rotation(170f).
                    withLayer().
                    setDuration(1000).
                    setInterpolator(interpolator).
                    start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make rotate.xml in res/anim:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate

        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="0"
        android:duration="1000" />

</set>
```

Then in code:

```
 FloatingActionButton mFloatingButton = view.findViewById(R.id.myFloatingButton);

        Animation mAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);

        mFloatingButton.startAnimation(mAnimation);
```

Comment: Use "this" instead "context", if it is in activity